# Why are there no pirate versions of Engi ships?

Tags: ftl-faster-than-light

Why don't pirates ever steal ships from the Engi? There are pirate versions of all the other enemy ship types (except for unique ships like the flagship and rock assault), but there aren't any for Engi ships.

For example, here are regular and pirate versions of the Rock Scout, from [the FTL wiki](https://ftl.fandom.com/wiki/Rock_Ships):

[image: Regular Rock Scout]
[image: Pirate Rock Scout]

Comment: Can you rephrase the question? I can't understand

Comment: @pinckerman It's a lore question.

Comment: There are also no pirate versions of crystal ships

Comment: @aytimothy it's not the lore that I'm questioning, the post was badly written.